# Detecting connection error and reconnection on Spring WebSocketClient

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

I am using Spring Framework's `WebSocketClient` and `WebSocketStompClient` to consume messages. The setup looks something like this:

```
    WebSocketClient webSocketClient = new StandardWebSocketClient();
    WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(webSocketClient);

    //messageConverter is MappingJackson2MessageConverter
    stompClient.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
    stompClient.setTaskScheduler(new ConcurrentTaskScheduler());

    WebSocketHttpHeaders httpHeaders = new WebSocketHttpHeaders();
    StompHeaders stompHeaders = new StompHeaders();
    //... populate authentication headers ... 

    stompClient.connect(url, httpHeaders, stompHeaders, this);
```

The class itself implements `StompSessionHandlerAdapter`.

I am then overriding the `afterConnected()` method to subscribe to the required destinations and all works well.

I am also overriding `handleException()`, and I was expecting that maybe when there is a connection error this would be triggered. I have a warning log inside, so I was expecting this to show something when a connection error occurs.

```
  @Override
  public void handleException(
      StompSession session,
      StompCommand command,
      StompHeaders headers,
      byte[] payload,
      Throwable exception) {
    logger.warn("Error on websocket session " + session.getSessionId(), exception);
  }
```

However, when there is a connection drop I see no error. The websocket server is accessible only through the private network, so the way I am trying to simulate it is by disconnecting VPN, at which point messages just stop (no Exception is logged through `handleException()`). Reconnecting VPN does not resume automatically either.

How can I detect that the websocket server is unavailable and try to reconnect periodically?

Comment: When you try to send a message through a disconnected socket, the sending should throw an execption. Try to catch this exception and reconnect the socket.

Comment: I am not sending any messages, just receiving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out there is another method, `handleTransportError()` which gets invoked when the socket connection drops. When I override it and the websocket server becomes unavailable it is correctly getting invoked.

```
  @Override
  public void handleTransportError(StompSession session, Throwable exception) {
    logger.warn("Error on websocket session " + session.getSessionId(), exception);

    // todo: schedule a reconnection attempt
  }
```

What I ended up doing is keeping a flag to know whether the client was connected or not. If this was the first disconnection it tries to re-establish the connection, otherwise it uses Spring's `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` to schedule a reconnection attempt after 5 seconds.

Comment: Do you have any sample code on how to re-connect from there?

Comment: Just put the connection code (in my original question) in a method called something like `startConnection()`, and call it again. Keep a flag to indicate that you are in `reconnection` state so that you don't try to reconnect multiple times too quickly.

Comment: I got a bit confused here, I need to handle the transport error but in my case my code is the server side... my client is a JavaScript one. Are you aware of any mitigation/recovery that can be done in ‘handleTransportError’ from server side? Trying to run down a disconnect...

Comment: @DavidFernandez I don't know much about Javascript clients sorry. In my case the client was another server-side application listening to events.

Comment: I understand that but in the end the errors seen from server side would be similar @jbx with use cases like abnormal disconnects, transport errors... basically graceful ways for the server to recover or leave things in a state the client can reconnect

Comment: @DavidFernandez not sure what you want me to tell you. My connection code is in the question. I just recall that when a transport error occurs.